# How to run multiple bash/sh scripts in setup.py file?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, setup.py

I have 2 scripts: `startup.sh` and `desktopsetup.sh` in the folder `bin`. Below is the code for my `setup.py`.

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install
import os

class MyInstall(install):
    def run(self):
        install.run(self)
        path = os.getcwd().replace(" ", "\ ").replace("(","\(").replace(")","\)") + "/bin/"
        os.system("echo 'Setting up Tzara.desktop'")
        os.system("chmod +x "+path+"desktopsetup.sh")
        os.system("sh "+path+"desktopsetup.sh")
        os.system("chmod +x "+path+"startup.sh")
        os.system("sh "+path+"startup.sh")


setup(name='Tzara---A-Personal-Assistant',
      version='1.0.6',
      description='A Virtual Personal Assistant',
      url='https://github.com/Suman7495/Tzara---A-Personal-Assistant',
      author='MyName',
      author_email='myemail@gmail.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['tzara'],
      classifiers=['Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',            
      ],
      scripts=['bin/desktopsetup.sh', 'bin/startup.sh'],
      cmdclass={'install': MyInstall},
)
```

When I run it, using `python install setup.py`, only `startup.sh` runs, `desktopsetup.sh` does not run.

Here is my `desktopsetup.sh` code:

```
#!/bin/bash
STR=$'[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Type=Application
Name=Tzara
Comment=A Virtual Personal Assistant
Exec=guake -n guake -t -e "python /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tzara/main.pyc" guake -r "Tzara"
Terminal=True
Type=Application
Categories=Application'
if [ ! -e /usr/share/applications/Tzara.desktop  ]; then
  echo "Setting up .desktop file"
  echo "$STR" | sudo tee sudo /usr/share/applications/Tzara.desktop > /dev/null
  read -n1 -r -p "Press any key to continue..." key
fi
```

Do find [the details of my code here.](https://github.com/Suman7495/Tzara---A-Personal-Assistant)

I would deeply appreciate if somebody could offer a little help.

Comment: check if `if [ ! -e /usr/share/applications/Tzara.desktop  ];` is true otherwise the file does nothing at all

Comment: `os.system("echo 'Setting up Tzara.desktop'")` this line too doesn't seem to be working, no output.

Comment: if it false you know it executed, why not keep a else block and echo something.

Comment: The issue is with your shebang line, `/` is missing.  More precisely, change `#!bin/bash` to `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Is it a good idea to mix shell code into your setup.py?

Comment: @codeforester I'm really sorry, but in the actual code the `/` is there, while posting the question I made a tiny mistake. Will correct it immediately.

Comment: @MKesper May not be. I basically want to a create a `.desktop` file, for a shortcut in the Menu, and this should be automatically done when I run the `setup.py` file. This is what I could come up with. In case you have a cleaner solution, I'd really appreciate if you could share it.